# Searching for string in files

Tags: grep, directory, search, recursive

Is there an easy way to search inside 1000s of files in a complex directory structure to find files which contain a specific string within the file?

Comment: Absolutely! Use a combination of find and grep commands. Here is an example http://wilddiary.com/find-files-containing-my-text/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
grep -H -R searchstring /directory
```

may want to redirect the results to a file (or tee)

You may also want to look at [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/)

Comment: Note that not all versions of grep support the -R option.

Comment: if grep does not support -R you can allways do: cat /directory/* | grep -H searchstring

Comment: @Wolfy, this is not the same, especially if you have a complex directory structure ... And `-H` does not help you here.

Comment: sorry, my mistake...

Comment: You can use find and xargs. `find -print0 -type f | xargs -0 grep -H searchstring`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is `grep`. It has an option for recursive directory traversal, e.g.:

```
$ grep -r specificstring path
```

With GNU `grep` you can restrict the searched files with the `--include` and `--exclude` pattern options.

`-H` ('Print the file name for each match') is the default with `-r`, `-R` and when you specify multiple files on the command line. `-R` also turns on recursive directory traversal but also follows symbolic links.

You can also pipe the results of `grep` to `less` for screen paging.