# How to search all subdirectories and their subdirectories for the occurence of a word using grep?

Tags: grep, recursive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching for string in files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14971/searching-for-string-in-files)

Suppose I have a directory called Home and it is my current directory.

And in this home directory I have many other directories

directory1, directory2, etc.

How do I do a grep to find the occurrence of a word (say "AXN") in any of the files in all of these subdirectories (and their subdirectories?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
grep -r "AXN" .
```

Use `-ir` if you want it to be case-insensitive.

Comment: I remember I had achieved this before using a "." or "./", but I forgot the syntax. Do you know how it could be done that way?

Comment: add a dot at the very end instead of the asterisk. using the dot is better, so it does not search binary files.

Comment: Dot will search binary files. Use the `-I` flag to skip them.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find / -type f -exec grep -il AXN {} +
```

Comment: To avoid issues with whitespace, you should use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` or `find ... -exec ... {} +` (or `{} \;` if you want only one at a time).

Comment: This may be functional but it involves launching a grep process for every file in the subdirectory. So, this may turn out be slower than `grep -r`

Comment: @Gowtham: like you, I prefer the xargs form, but the `+` on the end of that find command makes it construct a long command line like xargs does. i.e. `{} +` is different to plain `{}`.  xargs has other advantages, including `-P` or `--max-procs` to run multiple commands in parallel (very nice on a multi-core system when combined with `-n`)